# Error css id con elementos float, separa el contenido del div

Tags: css, html5

Tengo el siguiente código:

```css
  .left {
        padding-left: 10px;
        margin-left: 57px;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width: 45%;
        height: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .right {
        padding-left: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 45%;
        height: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #opacity {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72);
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        margin: 0;
    
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="opacity">
                <h2> 4Coach, Entrena con nosotros!</h2>
                <div class="left">
                    <p class="texto_c">
                        Las ideas que comunica un texto están contenidas en lo que se suele denominar «macroproposiciones», unidades estructurales de nivel superior o global, que otorgan coherencia al texto constituyendo su hilo central, el esqueleto estructural que cohesiona elementos lingüísticos formales de alto nivel, como los títulos y subtítulos, la secuencia de párrafos, etc. En contraste, las «microproposiciones» son los elementos coadyuvantes de la cohesión de un texto, pero a nivel más particular o local. Esta distinción fue realizada por Teun van Dijk en 1980.1
    
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <video width="800" height="600" controls class="video">
                        <source src="video/prueba1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        <!--PONER VARIOS FORMATOS PARA ASEGURAR LA REPRODUCCION mp4 compatible con todos los navegadores-->
                        Your browser does not support HTML video.
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr style="clear: both;" />
    </div>
```

La estructura del código necesito que se mantenga asi, soy consciente de que hay un `div` que contiene los demás pero es porque después le daré un diseño a parte. El error que tengo es que solo me sale el la parte opaca en el titulo del `div`, el texto y el vídeo se quedan completamente fuera, es como si el `id=opacity` no los englobara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es tan sencillo como subir un nivel la opacidad:

```css
 .left {
   padding-left: 10px;
   margin-left: 57px;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   width: 45%;
   height: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.right {
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#opacity {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72);
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin: 0;

}
```

```html
<div id="opacity">
  <div>
    <h2> 4Coach, Entrena con nosotros!</h2>
    <div class="left">
      <p class="texto_c">
        Las ideas que comunica un texto están contenidas en lo que se suele denominar «macroproposiciones», unidades estructurales de nivel superior o global, que otorgan coherencia al texto constituyendo su hilo central, el esqueleto estructural que cohesiona elementos lingüísticos formales de alto nivel, como los títulos y subtítulos, la secuencia de párrafos, etc. En contraste, las «microproposiciones» son los elementos coadyuvantes de la cohesión de un texto, pero a nivel más particular o local. Esta distinción fue realizada por Teun van Dijk en 1980.1

      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <video width="800" height="600" controls class="video">
        <source src="video/prueba1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <!--PONER VARIOS FORMATOS PARA ASEGURAR LA REPRODUCCION mp4 compatible con todos los navegadores-->
        Your browser does not support HTML video.
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr style="clear: both;" />
</div>
```

Al apuntar a un id css interpreta que el siguiente elemento es al que quieres dar el formato, entonces al subirlo un nivel coge el siguiente `div` como elemento al que quieres dar el estilo y te cubre lo completamente, si no solo te coge el `h2`

Comment: Toda la razón del mundo, muchas gracias.